# Userscripts to Remove a div by css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, userscripts

I want to remove a div by userscripts where only possible thing to differ the div is bacground image in inline css.

Suppose a div has the following CSS:
(background-image:http://www.example.com/example.png)

Could anyone help me about that?

I have tried the following one but not working.

```
var badDivs = $("div div:contains('background-image')");
badDivs.remove ();
```

Comment: im pretty sure :contains only looks for text

Comment: You could do something expensive like: grab every div and loop through them all with javascript checking for that style, but I would probably just add a class to the divs so you can target them with CSS and JQuery.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ badDivs.remove(); no hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$("div").each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("background-image") != 'none') {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Documentation: [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/), [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

WARNING!! checking ALL div will be a huge work, you should use a class like `toCheck` instead. So:

```
$(".toCheck").each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("background-image") != 'none') {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/df4Lq6Lf/2/).

```js
$(".toCheck").each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("background-image") != 'none') {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.toCheck {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#withImage {
  background-image: url("http://www.placehold.it/100/100");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toCheck" id="withImage">
  Div to check with an image
</div>

<div class="toCheck">
  Div to check without an image
</div>

<div>
  Normal div
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Since your class `toCheck` is partial-variable you will need a more tricky script using [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). First you need to extend JQUERY selectors ([tutorial](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/)) so for [`:regex`](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/):

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

then use it with your variable class:

```
$("div:regex(class, profile_view_img_+[0-9]*)").each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("background-image") != 'none') {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Updated [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/df4Lq6Lf/3/).

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}

$("div:regex(class, profile_view_img_+[0-9]*)").each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("background-image") != 'none') {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.toCheck {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#withImage {
  background-image: url("http://www.placehold.it/100/100");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile_view_img_22222222" id="withImage">
  Div to check with an image
</div>

<div class="profile_view_img_1111111">
  Div to check without an image
</div>

<div>
  Normal div
</div>
```

Comment: toCheck is not working, first one is working but its removing the whole page. If i use (background-image:http://www.example.com/example.png) this one then it not working again.

Comment: Thank you, i am giving you more details. The div class is not fixed. Check (<div class="width-48 height-48 profile_view_img_7474517"></div>) (7474517) this one is dynamic

Comment: Thank you very much. My last question, how can i use full background-image tag? instead of only background-image. ($(this).css("(background-image:example.com/example.png") instead of ($(this).css("background-image")

Comment: Use $(this).css("background-image") == 'url("example.com/example.png")' instead of $(this).css("background-image") != 'none'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127847/discussion-between-paolo-basso99-and-barkat-ullah).

Comment: You are totally awesome, finally its working. It saves me a lots of time. I don't know how to thank you. Have a good time always.